# update image if uploaded else use previosly stored image

Tags: php, database

```
<?php

include '../db_conx.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];   

$file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["college_image"]["tmp_name"]));


$insert_data1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['college_overview']);
$insert_data2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['college_courses']);
$insert_data3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['college_facilities']);

$test = "UPDATE college_details SET college_overview='$insert_data1', college_courses='$insert_data2', college_facilities='$insert_data3',college_image = '$file' where id = '$id' ";
if (mysqli_query($db_conx,$test)){
    header("Location:college.php?success");
}
{
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($db_conx));
}
?>
```

Whenever i try to update without uploading a new image the previously stored image gets removed. How do i keep the old image when no file is uploaded

Comment: Use a simple if else statement to check the $file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the upload file is empty or not using simple if else statement and reformat your sql statement accordingly:

```
if(!file_exists($_FILES["college_image"]["tmp_name"]) ||
 !is_uploaded_file($_FILES["college_image"]["tmp_name"])) {
   $test = "UPDATE college_details SET college_overview='$insert_data1',
              college_courses='$insert_data2', college_facilities='$insert_data3', 
              where id = $id ";
 //No file is uploaded, we skip updating the image.
}else{
   //Upload File is there, we update the image file in the database
     $test = "UPDATE college_details SET college_overview='$insert_data1',
              college_courses='$insert_data2', college_facilities='$insert_data3', 
              college_image = '$file' where id = $id ";
 }
```

Your code is vulnerable to sql injection. Use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to update your data.